# Symfony: Check ALL constraints, don't stop after the first violation

Tags: validation, symfony

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', TextType::class, array(
            'constraints' => array(
                new Length(array(
                    "min" => 2,
                    "max" => 7,
                )),
                new NotBlank(),
            ),
    ));
}
```

When this form is validated, I will only retrieve the first violation from the FormErrorIterator:

blank field -> NotBlank

Is there any option so I always retrieve ALL violations?

For example, if the field is blank, the FormErrorIterator should retrieve the NotBlank and MinLength violations!

Comment: This is the default behavior but looking at the constraint order you should put the `NotBlank` constraint before any other. The contraints are triggered following the order and you can't use the `Lenght` assert if a required field it's `null` or `empty`.

Answer (score 0):

I just looked into `LengthValidator`.

It seems like this is Constraint Validator-specific.
`LengthValidator` doesn't throw any violation at all if the value is empty.

If the value is not empty maxLength will be checked first. If it's a constraint violation it will be thrown and minLength will not be checked anymore.

It's a bit annoying. At least there sould be an option if values should will be checked anyway despite they're empty.